# How to RSYNC a single file?

Tags: linux, file, rsync

Currently i only RSync-ing the `Directories` as like:

```
* * * * * rsync -avz /var/www/public_html/images root@<remote-ip>:/var/www/public_html
```

So how do i `rsync` one single file like, `/var/www/public_html/.htaccess` ?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You do it the same way as you would a directory, but you specify the full path to the filename as the source. In your example:

```
rsync -avz --status=progress /var/www/public_html/.htaccess root@<remote-ip>:/var/www/public_html/
```

As mentioned in the comments: since `-a` includes *recurse*, one little typo can make it kick off a full directory tree transfer, so a more fool-proof approach might to just use `-vz`, or replace it with `-lptgoD`.

Comment: Also if you are only sending one file you may want to add the "--progress" parameter so you can watch it's progress.

Comment: does this mean that you still need a module in rsyncd.conf with a directory above the file (eg. with refuse option delete), or can you upload files anywhere on the server by just specifying it's path? The man page isn't really clear about that.

Comment: --partial --stats --progress
<< These flags are helpful if it's a really large file and may have to be resumed after a broken transfer.

Answer (score 18):

Basic syntax

```
rsync options source destination
```

Example

```
rsync -az /var/www/public_html/filename root@<remote-ip>:/var/www/public_html
```

[Read more](http://dasunhegoda.com/rsync-practical-examples/727/)

Answer (score 16):

Michael Place's answer works great if, relative to the root directory for both the source and target, all of the directories in the file's path already exist.

But what if you want to sync a file with this source path:

*/source-root/a/b/file*

to a file with the following target path:

*/target-root/a/b/file*

and the directories *a* and *b* don't exist?

You need to run an rsync command like the following:

```
rsync -r --include="/a/" --include="/a/b/" --include="/a/b/file" --exclude="*" [source] [target]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to just copy the individual file to an existing folder or create the folders in advance? In case of folder or folder content syncing let's rsync create all subfolders, after all it's its work, but in this particular case it's too much hassle and tricky the --include parameters just to copy individual files.

Comment: @user1598390 I'm not sure what scenario you're assuming, or imagining, where this would be less safe, but if you were trying to remember the specific form of this command and you didn't do it frequently, then yes it's probably less safe then copying the single file. It may be safer tho if the file is large, i.e. because rsync automatically handles most errors that could occur during copying. For some context, my syntax was particularly useful for me because I had written code that generated commands in this form so, given sufficient tests covering the relevant code, these commands are 'safe'.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the good above answers, **rsync expects the destination to be a *directory*** and not a *filename*.  Suppose you are copying the word list file `words` to /tmp, don't do this:

```
 rsync -az /user/share/dict/words /tmp/words    # does not work
```

'cp' is tolerant of this form, but rsync isn't - it will fail because it doesn't see a directory at `/tmp/words`. Snip off the destination filename and it works:

```
 rsync -az /user/share/dict/words /tmp
```

Note that rsync won't let you change the filename during the copy, and cp will.

Answer (score 1):

To date, two of the answers aren't quite right, they'll get more than one file, and the other isn't as simple as it could be, here's a simpler answer IMO.

The following gets exactly one file, but you have to create the dest directory with mkdir. This is probably the fastest option:

```
mkdir -p ./local/path/to/file
rsync user@remote:/remote/path/to/file/ -zarv --include "filename" --exclude "*" ./local/path/to/file/
```

If there is only one instance of file in /remote/path, rsync can create directories for you if you do the following. This will probably take a little more time because it searches more directories. Plus it's will create empty directories for directories in /remote/path that are not in ./local

```
cd ./local
rsync user@remote:/remote/path -zarv --include "*/" --include "filename" --exclude "*" .
```

Keep in mind that the order of --include and --exclude matters.