# Rsync: How can I exclude all except one particular file in a folder?

Tags: shell

I have route-eth1 file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scipts/. I need to exclude all the files except route-eth1 file during rsync ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can check this answer, it seems pretty close to your problem :
 [StackOverflow - rsync a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888012/how-to-rsync-a-single-file).

You can simply rsync directly the file by specifying the full path :

```
rsync avz /etc/sysconfig/network-scipts/route-eth1 root@<remote-ip>:/etc/sysconfig/network-scipts
```

Comment: Cant I do like --exclude network* init* ifup* ifdown* ifcfg* for excluding other files ??