# Rsync include a specific file under a certain structure

Tags: rsync

Following test structure:

```
src/
  one/
    one/
      file.txt
    two/
      file.txt
  two/
    file.txt
```

I only want to sync the file /one/two/file.txt.

I tried this but it does not work..

```
rsync -r --include='/one/two/file.txt' --exclude='*' src/ target/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you're using `--include`? If it's a single file then `rsync /one/two/file.txt /target/` would work.

Have a look at this answer:
[How to RSYNC a single file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888012/how-to-rsync-a-single-file)

If you're trying to send more than one file then you can use this, based on a pattern:
[Using Rsync include and exclude options to include directory and file by pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952000/using-rsync-include-and-exclude-options-to-include-directory-and-file-by-pattern)

Comment: Yes, my example was a bit over simplified. I need to include certain files in an excluded part of the tree from a big rsync. Your linked question gave me the answer. Including all directorys first gives me what I need.
rsync -r --include='/one' --include='*/two' --include='/one/two/file.txt' --exclude='*' src/ target/
Still if the nesting leven increases thats kind of ugly...

Comment: OK thanks. If you're answered the question, maybe mark this as resolved.